# How is it possible when opening a UISheetPresentationController, the ViewController under to remain the same and to not shrink?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have created a View Controller called RegistrationFormViewController, which is a basic registration form which opens on tap of the main view controller button. The question: Is there any possibility that when opening a UiSheetPresentationController the view controller behind to not shrink?

Snippet of my code when adding the UISheetPresentationController:

```
@objc func registerSheet(){
    var registrationSheet = RegistrationFormViewController()
   
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        if let sheet  = registrationSheet.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController{
            sheet.detents = [.medium()]
        }
    } else {
        self.present(registrationSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just ran into the same question. While at medium the previous view controller is still fullscreen. But any attempt to slide the sheet up to the large detent causes the previous view controller to start shrinking a bit.

Comment: @HangarRash / MrN just noticed the same thing happening to my app. Can't seem to find anything online, any updates form either of you?